# Saving last selected option in dropdown menu

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

I'm new to angular, I'm trying to save the select option tag, the language gets saved successfully however, the select option displays the English language by default even if I chose Arabic, when the page refreshes it gets back to English, I would appreciate if you can help me achieve this

footer.component.html

```
<div class="form-group">
   <select (change)="switchLanguage($event)" [ngModel]="lang" style="background-color: 
       #b3cee5;" class="form-control customized-dropdown alignleft">
       <option id="myLanguage" *ngFor="let item of Languages">{{item}}</option>
   </select>
</div>
```

footer.component.ts

```
directionEn: any;
directionAr: any
language;
userLang;
localsettings: LocalSettingsService;
Languages : any = ['English', 'Arabic'];
lang;


constructor(private translate: TranslateService) {
  translate.setDefaultLang('en');
}

switchLanguage(event) {
if(event.target.value == 'English'){
  this.language = 'en'
  this.lang = event.target.value;
  this.ChangeToEnglish()

} else if(event.target.value == 'Arabic'){
  this.language = 'ar'
  this.lang = event.target.value;
  this.ChangeToArabic();
}
this.translate.use(this.language);
localStorage.setItem('lang', this.lang)
localStorage.setItem('language', this.language);

}

ChangeToEnglish(){
  document.querySelector('body')
  .setAttribute('style', 'direction: ltr; text-align: left; ');
}
ChangeToArabic(){
  document.querySelector('body')
   .setAttribute('style', 'direction: rtl; text-align: right;');
}

ngOnInit() {
  var language = localStorage.getItem('language')
  var lang = localStorage.getItem('lang')

if(language === 'ar' && lang === "Arabic"){
  this.translate.use('ar');
  this.ChangeToArabic();
}
else if(language === 'en' && lang === "English"){
  this.translate.use('en');
  this.ChangeToEnglish()
}

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured out the solution, you just add a variable to each statement like this:

footer.component.ts

```
ngOnInit() {
  var language = localStorage.getItem('language')
  var lang = localStorage.getItem('lang')

if(language === 'ar' && lang === "Arabic"){
  this.translate.use('ar');
  this.ChangeToArabic();
  this.bind = "Arabic";
}
else if(language === 'en' && lang === "English"){
  this.translate.use('en');
  this.ChangeToEnglish()
  this.bind = "English";
}
```

footer.component.html

Just add [(ngModel)]="bind" to the select tag

```
<select (change)="switchLanguage($event)" [(ngModel)]="bind"
    style="background-color: #b3cee5;" class="form-control>
  <option id="myLanguage" *ngFor="let item of Languages">{{item}}</option>
 </select>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
constructor(private translate: TranslateService) {
  translate.setDefaultLang(localStorage.getItem('language') ? localStorage.getItem('language') : 'en');
}
```

Comment: this is working fine but still the select option is displaying English after I refresh the page

Comment: @Omar Are you certain that you're accessing the right item in your localstorage? Because that sounds to me, that you aren't at that the operator merely returns the "en" string.

Comment: var lang = localStorage.getItem('lang') is the line which returns a string either "Arabic" or "English", maybe I have troubles binding the value with the select tag